# while malloc fail, how to end the successive code without exit()?

Tags: c, malloc

While develop mobile App(**limited memory about 2Mb or less**), on `malloc()` fail, I have added a callback to report the error to UI, but the successive code still need to check the return value of `malloc()`, this may cause a lot of dirty code(check whether the returned memory is `NULL` or the `false` return code caused by allocation fail). is there a elegant way to terminate the successive code without exit() the whole App?

Comment: If you want to terminate all successive code then why is the `exit` not an option?

Comment: you could put the successive code in a separate function and only execute that if malloc was successful. that way you only have one more check and no excessive indentation

Comment: @nyarlathotep: Actually, I encapsulated the `malloc()` as `xmalloc()`, almost all the modules need it to request memory, I think it's not a wise way to put (all) the successive code in a separated function.

Comment: @nshy: I agree with that manner, but the UI module think its not a elegant way, that's why I added a callback to report the allocation failure, just like something says:"not enough memory..." and wait the user to terminate the App. Directly exit seems like a crash, user may think it's a serious bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean 'is there an elegant way to continue after memory allocation failure'?

Yes, there is, sort of, but it's quite difficult to do right. By playing with `setjmp` and `longump` you can give yourself some sort of emergency recovery system a little akin to try/catch, but you have to be **extremely** careful to clean up as you pass up the call stack.

Moreover, until your cleanup starts actually cleaning up allocated memory, any subsequent call to malloc is liable to fail.

Mostly, elegant is going to involve making sure you pass the error status back up the call stack though, and deal with it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to notify user by the means of some popup window and then terminate?

I don't know what library you are using - in win32 it would be easy as modal windows
have their own message loop, so you do not need to exit the function that initiates a modal dialog.

Anyway you call the exit after modal dialog finishes. If you want some real cleanup logic - 
it's hard and it's about whole program structure and design I think.

**UPDATE**:
By the way if memory is really low even popup may fail.

Comment: If the device runs Win32, I think the memory will at least about 256Mb...I think the best way is exit(), no another elegant options:)